# Increment issue in C (pointer)

Tags: c, pointers

I can only change the content of the "birthday" function, the rest must stay the same.

I am having a silly problem trying to increment the age variable...It does get incremented if I use the ++ operator but not by decimal 1, it seems to increment by 4 which is the sizeof an int. What am I doing wrong here ?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int* age;
    const char* name;
} Person;

void birthday(Person* person);


int main()
{
    void(*birthday_ptr)(Person* person) = &birthday;
    Person me = {30,"foobar"};
    (*birthday_ptr)(&me);
    return 0;
    }

void birthday(Person* person)
{
    printf("%p\n", person);
    printf("%d\n", person->age);
    person->age = 31; // this works...it sets the value pointed to by the ptr to 31...
    printf("%d\n", person->age);
    person->age += 1; // this compiles, but it seems to increment by 4 the value pointed to by the ptr, not 1 (relates to int size ?!)
    printf("%d\n", person->age);
    int* silly = (int*)(person);
    (*silly)++; // this works and increments age to 36...
    (*person->age)++; // this causes an access violation...why ?! 
    printf("silly: %d\n", person->age);
}
```

Comment: Everything will be simpler by using `int` and `std::string` in your struct, instead of `int *` (why ??) and `char *`

Comment: Your member `age` is a pointer to an integer. You have to dereference first before incrementing.

Comment: How can this compile?  `Person me = {30,"foobar"};` (30 is supposed to be a pointer).

My bad!! it compiles in C but not in C++

Comment: Note that you have to decide between C and C++, different languages

Comment: It's impossible to fix this by changing only the `birthday` function, because the struct initialization in `main` does not match the struct definition, so you'd need to change one of those.

Comment: Is `int* age` a typo? Shouldn't it be `int age`. If it's not a typo, it's a serious design error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution is to modify your struct:

```cpp
typedef struct {
    int age;
    const char* name;
} Person;
```

indeed, it is more logical that age is an `int` and not an `int*` (age is an integer not an adress of this form `0x1F8C45`).

With such a change, your code:

```c
    (person->age)++; // this causes an access violation...why ?!
    printf("silly: %d\n", person->age);
```

is correct.

If indeed, you would like to keep your `struct`as it currently is, you need to increment the value of member of the struct `int * age` but you can only change the content of the "birthday" function.

Here is my proposition.

**However, in my opinion, this is not a good C language nor is it a good practice. It is just a hack to bypass the problems'constraints (not to touch the structure) ==> You should be careful concerning the warning (also, your code does not compile if you use `-Werror` flag with `gcc` and consider the response of @Ayxan Haqverdili**.

Create a pointer pointing to the address of your `age`member

```cpp
// a pointer pointing to the address of person->age
 int *p = (&person->age);
 // increment the value pointed by the pointer (which is supposed to be age)
 ++*p; // person->age is 32
 ++*p; // person->age is 33
 (*p)++; // the same -- increment to 34 etc etc
```

The whole `birhday()` function is below

```cpp
void birthday(Person* person)
{
    printf("%d\n", person->age);
    person->age = 31; // this works...it sets the value pointed to by the ptr to 31...
    printf("%d\n", person->age);

    int *p = NULL;
    p = (int*)(&person->age);
    (*p)++; // age =32
    printf("value of p=%d\n", *p);
    printf("person->age=%d\n", person->age);

    (*p)++; // person->age is 33
    printf("value of p=%d\n", *p);
    printf("person->age=%d\n", person->age);


}
```

The ouput of the execution displays the following results:

```sh
30
31
value of p=32
person->age=32
value of p=33
person->age=33
```

Comment: @pussinboots1992 does this solution attempt contribute to solve your problem?

Comment: Hi, yes, this does solve my issue. Thanks, I also got it to work with something like this: ((int)*(person->age))++;

Comment: ((int)*(person->age))++;  ==> takes (person->age) which is a pointer. Dereference by adding `*` to extract the value pointed and cast it into `int`, and then increment it. 
Not bad as well

Comment: You're just causing undefined behavior. This is not a solution.

Comment: Can you please develop so that I can correct?

Comment: Firstly, you cannot use `%d` to print numeric value of a pointer

Comment: Secondly, using a pointer to store integer values is probably not going to make OP's teacher very happy.

Comment: And thirdly, `int *p = (&person->age);` is effectively type punning, which is also causing undefined behavior.

Comment: With proper warnings enabled, your code won't even compile. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/z4vq47

Comment: OK, I will improve the solution taking into account what you have said and I will post corrected solution. thanks

Comment: `char **nom = &(person->name);` is violating const-correctness

Comment: @pussinboots1992 this answer should not be accepted, even with the caveat.   The correct solution is to _not use a pointer for the `age` member variable_.   If you can't change that then at least explain what / who is imposing that constraint.

Answer (score 2):

You must dereference a pointer to change the value it's pointing to. But I reckon the age variable should not be a pointer at all. It should be an `int`:

```
typedef struct {
    int age;
    const char* name;
} Person;
```

This solves many of your problems, including the fact that you cast `30` to a pointer, and use `%d` to print the pointer, which causes undefined behavior.

Comment: He stated that `He can only change the content of the "birthday" function `

Comment: Yes I don't want to change the struct.

Comment: @pussinboots1992 then you have to allocate the integer elsewhere and set the pointer to address of that.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Can you elaborate ? What do you mean by "elsewhere", are you refering to scope or using the heap ?

Comment: @pussinboots1992 you can allocate it on the heap, or you can create a static int. Both are valid trade-offs.

Comment: @pussinboots1992 IMNSHO there is no valid use case for using a pointer there.  You _must_ change the structure.  If you can't, explain why not.